# How to send encrypted byte array data in bytea column via C# Npgsql query

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

What I want is to send encypted data from my app to PostgreSQL database via formatted string (query) by using Npgsql. Problem is that after sha256.ComputeHash() I get byte array which I'm trying to send by inserting it into my string query. It works fine but then in my dbms column I see System.Byte[] instead of byte array. How can I fix that?

My string query is something like that:

````
private readonly SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
string sql = $"""
                    INSERT INT table(encrypted_column) VALUES (
                                                            '{sha256.ComputeHash(data)}'); 
                    """;
```[What in db after Query][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ch7t.png
````

Comment: But `System.Byte[]` is a byte array.

Comment: Yes but in PostgreSQL it stores sting that value is "System.Byte[]" instead of byte array that was encrypted.

Comment: I say it again: `System.Byte[]` ***is*** a byte array. You can use one instead of another, and nothing will change.

Comment: Yes it's a byte array but the problem is how it sends in request as a string called "Byte Array " instead of byte array itself. Let me add screenshot of my DataGrip.

Comment: You say it sends a *string* "System.Byte[]" instead of the array?

Comment: Yes and I need query to send byte array instead of the string that just says it's type

Comment: Where does the requirement of "via formatted string" come from? Why can't you use parameterized SQL and set the parameter value to the byte array, thus avoiding the problem?

Comment: Oh wow. I haven't seen this way of usage. I thought that formatted string is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SHA256.ComputeHash()` returns a byte array. It is converted to a string implicitly, using `ToString()`. And it just returns the type string for byte array. You should use this query:

```cs
string sql = $"""INSERT INTO table (encrypted_column) VALUES ('{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sha256.ComputeHash(data))}');""";
```

Answer (score 0):

So using a formatted string was a bad idea. Thanks to SNBS better way is to use parameters: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html